# A google script to import data from a website that requires authentication, a username and a password. The data is dynamic

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to ask if there is a google script to import data from a website that requires authentication, a username and a password. The data is dynamic.

I'd be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) inside Google Apps Script to request data from a distant website. As this class supports headers, you can easily authenticate the request.

Assuming the website use a Basic authentication method, you can do it like this:

```js
var username = "..."
var password = "..."
var credentials = Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)

var options = {
  'method' : 'get',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials
  }
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.org', options);
```

Then you can do something with the response, depending on the response type. Note that your script will require the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` authorization scope.